# UIView Linear Animation Moving View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

My intention is to move a UIView Object.

The Code I use for this is:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:(biggestViewWidth * 0.005) delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{


            //
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];

            // View verschieben
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(-view.frame.size.width - 10, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];

        } ...
```

But as is the example shown the view is linear moved to the new x position. Is it possible to say that the Animation should go with a step of 20 points for example more and more to the left?
So for example:
startX = 0;
1. = -20;
2. = -40;
.
.
.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to customize the animation curves. The easiest is to pass in one of these to your existing function: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#jumpTo_153

Otherwise, you can setup your own animation using keyframes as in this example: https://github.com/ShinobiControls/iOS7-day-by-day/blob/master/11-uiview-keyframe-animation/11-uiview-keyframe-animation.md

Comment: Can you post an concret example of my problem. Would be very helpful because I don't get it.